# 動画ファイルアップロード時にメモリリーク「EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY (limit=1850 mb unused=0x0)」になる

Tags: ios, unity2d

Unityで開発を行っております。
最大500MB以下の動画ファイルのアップロードを変数付きでアップロード行いたく下記のコードを作成しました。

```
// ファイル読み込み
byte[] l_file_data = File.ReadAllBytes( _path );
string l_fileName = "hoge.mp4";

var request = new UnityWebRequest( l_url, "POST");
setRequest( request );
// タイムアウト設定
request.timeout = 300;

List<IMultipartFormSection> requestData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
requestData.Add( new MultipartFormFileSection( "file", l_file_data, l_fileName, "video/*" ) );

if( 0 < user_id )
    requestData.Add( new MultipartFormDataSection( "user_id",               user_id.ToString() ) );
if( 0 < player_id )
    requestData.Add( new MultipartFormDataSection( "player_id",             player_id.ToString() ) );
if( 0 < group_id )
    requestData.Add( new MultipartFormDataSection( "group_id",              group_id.ToString() ) );
if( 0 < team_id )
    requestData.Add( new MultipartFormDataSection( "team_id",               team_id.ToString() ) );
if( 0 < game_id )
    requestData.Add( new MultipartFormDataSection( "game_id",               game_id.ToString() ) );

if( !title.Equals( "" ) )
    requestData.Add( new MultipartFormDataSection( "title",                 System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( title ) ) );
if( !comment.Equals( "" ) )
    requestData.Add( new MultipartFormDataSection( "comment",               System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( comment ) ) );

byte[] boundary = UnityWebRequest.GenerateBoundary();
byte[] formSections = UnityWebRequest.SerializeFormSections( requestData, boundary );

// データ設定
request.uploadHandler   = (UploadHandler) new UploadHandlerRaw( formSections );
request.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler) new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
 
// ヘッダを設定
request.SetRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest" );
request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(boundary) );
request.SetRequestHeader( "Authorization", "Bearer "+ _access_token );
// アプリ名、Ver、プラットフォーム
request.SetRequestHeader("X-Escore-Env", "app="+APP_NAME+"; ver="+VER+"; os="+isOS() );

yield return request.Send();
```

こちらUnityエディター上や、動画容量の少ないファイルでしたらアップロードが出来るのですが、
100MB以上のファイルになった際にiPadがハングしてしまいます。
ハング内容は「EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY (limit=1850 mb unused=0x0)」になります。
100MBの動画ファイルをアップしているのですが、メモリが800MB近く増えます。
Windows エディター上ではこのような現象は発生しておりません。

こちらハングせずにアップロードする方法何かご存じでしょうか

環境
Unity 2018.4.22f1

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/2018.4/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Send.html 曰く Send() は「AsyncOperation オブジェクトを返します。コルーチン内部に非同期処理(AsyncOperation)を与えるとシステムエラーが発生するか、または通信が終了するまでコルーチンが一時停止する原因となります。」とあります。Unityには詳しくないので、これが質問の解決策に関係があるのかないのかよくわかりませんが、参考までに…

Comment: 現在調査しているのですが、どうやら送信時の処理でexc_resource resource_type_memory (limit=1850 mb unused=0x0)とメモリリークが発生しておりました。120MBほどの動画ファイルアップロードに対してメモリが800MB近く膨れ上がってハングしておりました。こちら原因何かありますでしょうか。